# What are missed lines in fail2ban?

Tags: log-files, fail2ban

I had millions of lines such as these in my log file yesterday:

```
Feb 25 18:00:00 mond2 sshd[29574]: Bad protocol version identification '\003' from 54.37.78.250 port 50306
Feb 25 18:00:00 mond2 sshd[29575]: Bad protocol version identification '\003' from 54.37.78.250 port 50530
Feb 25 18:00:00 mond2 sshd[29576]: Bad protocol version identification '\003' from 54.37.78.250 port 50696
Feb 25 18:00:00 mond2 sshd[29577]: Bad protocol version identification '\003' from 54.37.78.250 port 50857
Feb 25 18:00:00 mond2 sshd[29578]: Bad protocol version identification '\003' from 54.37.78.250 port 51032
Feb 25 18:00:01 mond2 sshd[29579]: Bad protocol version identification '\003' from 54.37.78.250 port 51213
Feb 25 18:00:01 mond2 sshd[29580]: Bad protocol version identification '\003' from 54.37.78.250 port 51427
Feb 25 18:00:01 mond2 sshd[29584]: Bad protocol version identification '\003' from 54.37.78.250 port 51642
Feb 25 18:00:01 mond2 sshd[29585]: Bad protocol version identification '\003' from 54.37.78.250 port 51809
Feb 25 18:00:01 mond2 sshd[29586]: Bad protocol version identification '\003' from 54.37.78.250 port 51970
```

And I wanted to catch them with fail2ban by creating a new jail for it. But nothing worked. Now I tried the regex tester and it tells me this:

```
fail2ban-regex /var/log/auth.log.test "^%(__prefix_line)sBad protocol version identification '\\\d+' from <HOST> port"

Running tests
=============

Use   failregex line : ^%(__prefix_line)sBad protocol version identificat...
Use         log file : /var/log/auth.log.test
Use         encoding : UTF-8


Results
=======

Failregex: 0 total

Ignoreregex: 0 total

Date template hits:
|- [# of hits] date format
|  [10] (?:DAY )?MON Day 24hour:Minute:Second(?:\.Microseconds)?(?: Year)?
`-

Lines: 10 lines, 0 ignored, 0 matched, 10 missed [processed in 0.00 sec]
|- Missed line(s):
|  Feb 25 18:00:00 mond2 sshd[29574]: Bad protocol version identification '\003' from 54.37.78.250 port 50306
|  Feb 25 18:00:00 mond2 sshd[29575]: Bad protocol version identification '\003' from 54.37.78.250 port 50530
|  Feb 25 18:00:00 mond2 sshd[29576]: Bad protocol version identification '\003' from 54.37.78.250 port 50696
|  Feb 25 18:00:00 mond2 sshd[29577]: Bad protocol version identification '\003' from 54.37.78.250 port 50857
|  Feb 25 18:00:00 mond2 sshd[29578]: Bad protocol version identification '\003' from 54.37.78.250 port 51032
|  Feb 25 18:00:01 mond2 sshd[29579]: Bad protocol version identification '\003' from 54.37.78.250 port 51213
|  Feb 25 18:00:01 mond2 sshd[29580]: Bad protocol version identification '\003' from 54.37.78.250 port 51427
|  Feb 25 18:00:01 mond2 sshd[29584]: Bad protocol version identification '\003' from 54.37.78.250 port 51642
|  Feb 25 18:00:01 mond2 sshd[29585]: Bad protocol version identification '\003' from 54.37.78.250 port 51809
|  Feb 25 18:00:01 mond2 sshd[29586]: Bad protocol version identification '\003' from 54.37.78.250 port 51970
`-
```

So it obviously has no idea what I want. What does that even mean, lines were missed? Did it not look carefully and forgot what it has just read? Did it read too fast to actually process what it has read? I don't get it, neither does the web. Is there any explanation for this?

And what would I have to do to match and ban these log lines?

Here's the regex I started with, no idea whether it's good:

```
failregex = ^%(__prefix_line)sBad protocol version identification '\\\d+' from <HOST> port \d+\s*$
```

I have Fail2Ban v0.9.3 on Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I played some more to find a working solution. The only thing I could find was removing everything I had added and only adding this to the `sshd` jail, in `jail.local`:

```
failregex = ^\s*\S+\s+sshd\[\d+\]: Bad protocol version identification '.*?' from <HOST> port
```

This seems to work. When I connect with netcat and enter some text, the relevant log line shows up and `fail2ban-client status sshd` increments a failed counter by 1. I'm not fully sure because there's also other attacks going on (the usual background noise).

The key change in the regex was not to overly specify the part after "identification".

Comment: This is built in in more recent versions of `fail2ban`, and enabled with `mode = aggressive`.  [More info and other options here](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/issues/1284).

Answer (score 2):

I am a bit rusty, but `missed lines` refers to **lines with no match** against your regular expression.

The following command will show matching and missed lines from your log:

```
fail2ban-regex --print-all-missed /var/log/auth.log.test "^%(__prefix_line)sBad protocol version identification '\\\d+' from <HOST> port"
```

As far as I recall each line will have a prefix will saying `HIT:` if regex matches and `MISS:` if there are no match.

**EDIT**

Sitting at a computer now, trying to debug your statement.

First of maybe the regex is cut a bit short? Because the regex does not match the whole line.

As far as i can tell the regex matches:

`Feb 25 18:00:00 mond2 sshd[29574]: Bad protocol version identification '\003' from 54.37.78.250 port` 50306

Noticed I havent marked the port number.

What if you expanded the regex, so it says:

```
^%(__prefix_line)sBad protocol version identification '\\\d+' from <HOST> port \d+
```

Hmm... Tried test log with my own server and that still didn't work. Suspecting that the `__prefix_line` part does not not match everything up to before "Bad protocol".